# Is Android /res/xml/phonegap.xml the same as phonegap.plist for iOS?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, plist

I'm looking for the available phonegap.xml options.

Specifically, I have been told to use the Android equivalent of ShowSplashScreenSpinner in my phonegap.xml file to solve a problem I have but have been unable to solve this yet.

Can anyone assist?